# VB export listview to Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, listview, extract

I keep getting 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC' error when I run my code.
Some forums say that the '1' needs to be changed to a '0' or vice versa.
At this point I just don't know what is wrong nothing is sticking out. I believe I have all the references loaded that I need, so any suggestions/help would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim bkWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim shWorkSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    objExcel = New Excel.Application
    bkWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
    shWorkSheet = bkWorkBook.ActiveSheet
    For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Columns.Count
        shWorkSheet.Cells(1, Chr(64 + i)) = Me.ListView1.Columns(i)
    Next
    For i = 1 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count
        shWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, "A") = Me.ListView1.Items(i).Text
        For j = 2 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count
            shWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, Chr(64 + j)) = Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(j - 1)
        Next
    Next

    objExcel.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I retested and found I hadn't fully tested a listview with more than a couple of columns. Try this:

```
    Try
        Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
        Dim bkWorkBook As Workbook
        Dim shWorkSheet As Worksheet
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer

        objExcel = New Excel.Application
        bkWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
        shWorkSheet = CType(bkWorkBook.ActiveSheet, Worksheet)
        For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
            shWorkSheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = Me.ListView1.Columns(i).Text
        Next
        For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1
                shWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = Me.ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
            Next
        Next

        objExcel.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried your method as well, but I still get an error:'ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled'; InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'. For the 7th line of code you provided. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect! I had to take out the catch ex as exception and msgbox part. Do I truely need that part?

Answer (score 1):

```
shWorkSheet.Cells(1, Chr(64 + i))
```

should be

```
shWorkSheet.Cells(1, i)
```

Cells expects one or two numeric arguments.

Comment: @ Tim:  Thanks for the response.  I get a COMException was unhandled when I tried that solution.  Does this mean I'm missing a COM reference?

Comment: Column indexes are 1-based, so i should start at 1

Comment: I made sure the index started with 1 on those cases, so I don't know why it errors still.

Answer (score 1):

This code only add : CreateObject and autofiT rows and columns

```
  Public Sub ExportLw2Excel(Lw As ListView)
    Try
        Dim objExcel As Object ' New Excel.Application
        objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Dim bkWorkBook As Object 'As Workbook
        Dim shWorkSheet As Object 'As Worksheet
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer

        'objExcel = New Excel.Application
        bkWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
        shWorkSheet = bkWorkBook.activesheet '  CType(bkWorkBook.ActiveSheet, Worksheet)
        For i = 0 To Lw.Columns.Count - 1
            shWorkSheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = Lw.Columns(i).Text
        Next
        For i = 0 To Lw.Items.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To Lw.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1
                shWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = Lw.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
            Next
        Next

        objExcel.Cells.Select
        objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        objExcel.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
        objExcel.Range("A1:B1").Select
        objExcel.Selection.Font.Bold = True
        objExcel.Range("A1").Select

        objExcel.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very muchly. This worked great for me. It was the createobject that I needed to use as I didn't have some reference I guess for the chosen answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution if you want to export your listview with colored lines to Excel. Please position the indexes correctly according to your ListViews Rows and Columns indexes!!

```
Try
    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim bkWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim shWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    objExcel = New Excel.Application
    bkWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
    shWorkSheet = CType(bkWorkBook.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)
    For i = 0 To objLv.Columns.Count - 1
        shWorkSheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = objLv.Columns(i).Text
    Next

    For i = 0 To objLv.Items.Count - 1
        Dim clr = ColorTranslator.ToOle(objLv.Items(i - 1).BackColor)
        shWorkSheet.Rows(i).Interior.Color = clr
        For j = 2 To objLv.Columns.Count
                shWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j - 1).Value = objLv.Items(i - 1).SubItems(j - 1).Text
        Next
    Next

    objExcel.Visible = True
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```